# Subtracting dates in SQL Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm sure this is super simple, but I am still very new to SQL. I am trying to subtract two dates, but one date is just a birthyear in an integer format and the other I would like for it to be the current date. I am trying to find age of these individuals. Any help would be greatly appreciated! What i have so far is below. Thank you!

```
select 
  distinct(count(usertype)), 
  gender, usertype, 
  date_diff(extract(year from current_date) as current_year, tripdata.birth_year, year)

from  `project-1-349215.Dataset.tripdata`
```

Comment: If you are just wanting to subtract years (which makes sense) then you don't need to use any date functions. Years are just numbers: `extract(year from current_date) as current_year - tripdata.birth_year` will suffice.

Comment: Unrelated, `DISTINCT` is not a function. `SELECT DISTINCT(count(usertype)), gender FROM mytable` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT count(usertype), gender FROM mytable`. Perhaps you meant `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT usertype)`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding and for the tip on the count distinct function. When I use this code i still get an error for an expected ending but instead got "-" for some reason it is flagging the minus sign. 

select count(distinct(usertype)), gender, usertype, 
extract(year from current_date) as current_year - tripdata.birth_year as age

from  `project-1-349215.Dataset.tripdata`

Comment: Oh! My apologies. I was so busy copy and pasting your code that I missed the syntax error. You want `extract(year from current_date) - tripdata.birth_year`. The `as current_year` aliasing is something that you can only do to the result of the function/math being applied. So `extract(year from current_date) - tripdata.birth_year as age` would be appropriate if you want the resulting column to be named `age`.

Comment: Note that you will still have errors throwing because you are aggregating `usertype` in the `count()` function, but you lack a GROUP BY clause. Furthermore it doesn't make sense to `count(usertype)` and include `usertype` itself in the SELECT. There will always be just `1` `count(usertype)` for each distinct `usertype`.

Comment: This seems to have accomplished exactly what i was needing! thank you so much for your help. I'm sure it takes time and experience to recognize these kinds of things!

Answer (score 0):

Posting @JNevill's suggestion in the comment section as wikianswer:

```
with tripdata as (
  select 1995 as birth_year, "premium" as usertype, "F" as gender,
  union all select 1990 as birth_year, "standard" as usertype, "F" as gender,
  union all select 1990 as birth_year, "standard" as usertype, "F" as gender,
  union all select 1993 as birth_year, "standard" as usertype, "F" as gender,
  union all select 1993 as birth_year, "premium" as usertype, "M" as gender,
  union all select 1994 as birth_year, "premium" as usertype, "F" as gender,
)

select 
  count(usertype), 
  gender,
  extract(year from current_date) - tripdata.birth_year as age
from tripdata
group by usertype, gender, tripdata.birth_year;
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
date_diff(Column1,column2,day) As  date_diff_days
```

if you want to perform difference in minute and seconds --> change day to minute and seconds.